# Left Outer Join with a subquery not executing oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to make a query for that contains left outer join and a query that contains a sub query. I tried the following code:

```
select c.CustomerName,l.Way,l.Travel
from (select l.HomeAdd from tbl_Location l
where l.HomeAdd like '%Colombo%') from
tbl_Customer c left outer join tbl_Location l
on (l.location_id=c.location_id);
```

I get the following error message

```
tbl_Customer c left outer join tbl_Location l
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Please help!!!

Comment: I have made changes to the Code Please check above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist upon using a subquery I suggest you do something like:

```
select c.CustomerName,
       l.Way,
       l.Travel
from tbl_Customer c
left outer join (SELECT l.HOMEADD,
                        l.WAY,
                        l.TRAVEL
                 FROM tbl_Location
                 WHERE l.HOMEADD LIKE 'Colombo%') l
  on l.location_id=c.location_id
```

Also, a comment: I strongly suggest that you should not prefix the names of tables etc, with something like 'TBL_'. When tables, etc, are used the context of the usage tells you what the object is. Oracle identifiers are limited to 30 characters - IMO sacrificing 13% of the available name length to a prefix is simply wasteful.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 4):

Very strange query.  I assume you intend:

```
select c.CustomerName, l.Way, l.Travel
from tbl_Customer c left outer join
     tbl_Location l
     on l.location_id = c.location_id and l.HomeAdd like 'Colombo%';
```

The problem with your query is you have subquery in the `where` clause.  There is no comparison -- not `=`, no `exists`, no `in`, nothing that represents a boolean expression.

Comment: i used the following link http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/subqueries.php this tells about sub query and I tried to apply that to left outer join. Is it possible to create a query like that?

Comment: I might be asking a silly question, but just to make sure does this contain  a sub query?

Comment: @Andrew . . . This version does not contain a subquery.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are missing EXISTS keyword in the query

```
select c.CustomerName,l.Way,l.Travel
from tbl_Customer c left outer join tbl_Location l
on (l.location_id=c.location_id)
where EXISTS (
  select l.HomeAdd from tbl_Location l
  where l.HomeAdd like 'Colombo%'
);
```

Comment: Which transforms to `INNER JOIN`

Comment: that's true :) Also, there would be no link between the query and subquery, so it would always return something if there would be any record in the table with address like 'Colombo%'

Comment: Its says no rows selected. Can you please tell me what sub sub queries can I make for an outer Join?

Comment: Replace `Where` with `AND` to fix the problem

Comment: Gordons answer should be the one you are looking for :)

Comment: I have made changes to the Code Please check above